# Custom module to redirect anonymous users from a specific url not working (yet)

Tags: redirection

I am trying to write a simple custom module to redirect anonymous users when they want to access certain urls, but it is not working. What am I missing?

Here's the entire code:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
    $items['mypath/%']['access callback'] = 'redirect_and_remember_url';
}

function redirect_and_remember_url(){

    global $user;
    if ($user->uid){
            return TRUE;
        }
    else {
        drupal_goto('subscribe', array('query'=>drupal_get_destination()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
   global $user;
   if (!$user->uid) {
       $items['mypath/%']['page callback'] = 'redirect_and_remember_url';
   }
}

function redirect_and_remember_url(){
   drupal_goto('subscribe', array('query'=>drupal_get_destination()));
}
```

Comment: This looks much better, I edited my code. However, the module still has no effect. I wonder if it's a more global problem.

Comment: This won't work unfortunately - menu routes are cached so testing the current user in `hook_menu_alter()` doesn't make sense, and won't do what you hope. You need to make the decision in the page callback itself

Comment: I agreed with Clive